# CakePHP URL - specify a named filed as "null"

Tags: cakephp

I am working on an app that connects to a 3rd party CakePHP API system.
Here is a sample output of the url:

```
https://<server>/api/events.json
```

Output:

```
{"events":[{"Event":{"Id":"11902","MonitorId":"5","Name":"New Event","Cause":"Continuous","StartTime":"2016-08-15 17:10:00","EndTime":null,"Width":"2304","Height":"1296","Length":"319.81","Frames":"1600","AlarmFrames":"0","TotScore":"0","AvgScore":"0","MaxScore":"0","Archived":"0","Videoed":"0","Uploaded":"0","Emailed":"0","Messaged":"0","Executed":"0","Notes":""},"thumbData":""},{"Event":{"Id":"11903","MonitorId":"7","Name":"New Event","Cause":"Continuous","StartTime":"2016-08-15 17:10:00","EndTime":"2016-08-15 17:11:00" ,"Width":"1280","Height":"720","Length":"316.73","Frames":"1900","AlarmFrames":"0","TotScore":"0","AvgScore":"0","MaxScore":"0","Archived":"0","Videoed":"0","Uploaded":"0","Emailed":"0","Messaged":"0","Executed":"0","Notes":""},"thumbData":""}
```

Note that in some cases, `EndTime` field is null and in some cases it is not. I now want to craft a URL that only returns fields where EndTime is null.

The API allows for named filters. For example:

`https://<server>/api/events/index/EndTime >=: 2016-11-07 10:10:10.json`

Accurately returns all values with EndTime > the value specified.

How does one ask for EndTime = null?

I tried:

`https://<server>/api/events/index/EndTime =: null.json`

That doesn't work (also tried with quotes)

thanks

Comment: How could anyone tell without even knowing what API you are actually talking about? Shouldn't you ask the ones that provide the API? There is no rule for how to indicate `null` in a URL.

Comment: Okay ,thanks, I wasn't sure if there was a fixed rule to specify an empty field. After digging around, I found the answer `https://<server>/api/events/index/EndTime =:.json`